# undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a posting system that allows for comments. 
I am making a notification system and am getting this error:

NoMethodError in CommentsController#create
undefined method `user' for nil:NilClass

I think that user is defined as a post attribute, and I'm calling the post so it should be okay.

Here is the create method

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        create_notification @post
        format.html { redirect_to request.referer, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

It should be noted that I was following a tutorial for part of it, and it orginially had the line "create_notification @post, @comment", but that created an argument error later.

Here is the method create_notification, the error is in the second line

```
def create_notification(post)  
      return if post.user.id == current_user.id
      Notification.create(user_id: post.user.id,
                        notified_by_id: current_user.id,
                        post_id: post.id,
                        comment_id: comment.id,
                        notice_type: 'comment')
    end
```

It starts at the second line, and if commented out, it moves on to the next lines.

Here is the app trace

```
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:71:in `create_notification'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:33:in `block in create'
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:31:in `create'
```

Comment: You're passing `@post` to your `create_notification` method but where are you defining `@post`?

Comment: Well, a comment is associated with a post, not the same thing, but I assumed that would be enough. This is part of the new comment form: <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>. They are also associated in their models.

Comment: You know what happens when you assume? Your method is expecting an argument; in this case, a Post object. You are, however, passing nil to it as `@post` isn't defined. Also, in this context, your form has nothing to do with what you're passing to your `create_notification` method.

Comment: You're right, I know I shouldn't assume things and programming is very technical, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NoMethodError in CommentsController#create undefined method `user' for
>   nil:NilClass

In `create_notification @post`, `@post` is `nil` Make sure you have defined `@post`. For instance `@post = Post.find(params[:comment][:post_id])`